# How to show process status on a switch in android?

Tags: android, switchcompat

In the material design guide there is a section called "**Display processing status**" where we see a video of a Switch with a progress indicator on the thumb.

https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#switches

> Because a switch shows the actual status of something, sometimes there is a delay in its change of state. In such cases, a processing status animation can be used.
>
> A processing status is an animation on the thumb of the switch. For example, it can be used when a switch that controls a hardware feature experiences a delay before its final status can be confirmed.

How can I achieve such an effect? is that part of the normal CompatSwitch? Is there a library that does this?

Comment: Did you found how can be done this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an idea that may help you. You can use the custom image/drawable inside switches with help of switch `thumb` property

```
<Switch
android:id="@+id/switch_one"
. . .
android:track="@drawable/switch_track_custom"
android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_custom"/>
```

For state change, you can use `Selecter`. [this](https://www.zoftino.com/android-switch-button-and-custom-switch-examples) blog gives you a good idea.

Here are some other blog and libraries

- https://medium.com/@elye.project/customizing-switch-using-xml-ca0d37204a86
- https://github.com/Angads25/android-toggle
- https://github.com/glomadrian/material-animated-switch
- https://github.com/kovpas/PMZSwitch

Answer (score 0):

However, I think that video is just to demonstrate '**DO NOT DO THIS'**. Because it clearly says

**Don't demonstrate status by animating the thumb of a switch.**